# Input in VBScript and HTML

Tags: vbscript, textbox, frontpage

I am creating a program to calculate sum of 2 digits entered by the user in text fields in Front Page. In JAVA NetBeans .getText() method is used to extract the text from the text fields. Which method is used to do the same in Front Page. I am using VBScript code in Front Page. Kindly help with a sample code. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get the field value. I think? Didn't test. You should be able to cut and paste in Front Page to validate.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>sample xyz</TITLE></HEAD>
<SCRIPT Language = "VBScript">
<!--
Sub getIt_OnClick()
    Dim val_myField
    val_myField = myField.value
    MsgBox "field value is " & val_myField
End Sub
-->
</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
<BR>
some field: <INPUT Type="Text" Name="myField" Value="100000"><BR>
<INPUT Type="Button" Name="getIt" Value="myValue">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: testing would have caught the missing `val_`.

Comment: ah yes my bad. was just editing it incorrectly while trying to find something I could validate html vbs in, but looks like you took care of it.